# Map showing the change in precipitation intensity

Tags: models, rainfall, mapping

Hi I need a map for the North American region that shows the change in rainfall intensity. Unfortunately, I can only find maps like this [map](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/Water/page3.php)

Unfortunately, these are not detailed to use.

Comment: You can use reanalysis (e.g. ERA5) and create the map yourself. A quick google search got me to this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212096315000054 which might be a good starting point. You state that the maps you found are "not detailed sufficiently", but we don't know what "detailed sufficiently" means to you.

Comment: https://www.ventusky.com/?p=42.5;-100.4;3&l=precipitation-anomaly